# counting the occurrences of a field on a individual line

Tags: awk, field, counting

I am trying to take a file that has many 1000's of lines, and for each lines I would like to count the occurrences that the individuals fields occur. So an example of a few lines of the file look like this:

```
0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/1     0/0     0/0     1/1     0/0     0/1
0/1     1/1     0/1     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0
```

my code is this:

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN{a=0; c=0; g=0;} {a+=gsub("0/0",""); c+=gsub("0/1",""); g+=gsub("1/1","")} END{print a,c,g}'
```

The output that I get is:
  18 4 2

The output that I want is:

```
    line #1- 9 2 1
    line #2- 9 2 1
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: useless use of `cat`. `file` should be the argument of `awk`. I must admit that I don't get the remaining part of the question

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. What I am trying to do is that in my file (labeled file here, hence the cat, and understood that it is not needed in this way), there are these strings of '0/0, 0/1, 1/1'. For each line, I would like to count the occurrences of each one. My awk line seems to merged all of the lines into 1 and doesn't separate it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print "line #", NR, "-", gsub("0/0",""), gsub("0/1",""), gsub("1/1","")}' file
```

Comment: What if there is `1/0`?

Comment: I do know that in my dataset, there are only 3 possibilities: 0/0, 0/1, and 1/1.

Comment: @user1352084 Got it. I didn't think of that and went towards a more generic approach to cover all scenarios. Glad this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk` you can try something like this (The output can be random. Since you haven't mentioned the order you'd like to get, I am assuming this should be ok):

```
awk '{delete a; printf "line #%s- ", NR; for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) a[$x]++; for(y in a) printf "%s ", a[y]; print ""}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ cat file
0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/1     0/0     0/0     1/1     0/0     0/1
0/1     1/1     0/1     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0
$ awk '{delete a; printf "line #%s- ", NR; for(x=1;x<=NF;x++) a[$x]++; for(y in a) printf "%s ", a[y]; print ""}' file
line #1- 9 2 1 
line #2- 9 2 1
```